# ExtJS 4 vertically fit container

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4.1

I've two nested container and I wanto to fit vertically (only vertically) the first container to the page size, and the second container to the first container size.

In case of resize of the page all containers should resize themselves automatically.

I'm not able to do this feature. I think that is a layout problem.

This is my sample code and my jsfiddle:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    layout:'fit',
    flex:1,
    width:100,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype:'container',
        layout : {
                type : 'vbox',
                align : 'stretch'

            },
        items:[
    {
                    //this is the right panel not collapsible
                    xtype : 'panel',
                    border:true,
                    //hidden:false,
                    bodyBorder:true,
                    padding: '5 5 5 5',

                    itemId:'right',

                    //default layout of inner element is hbox
                    layout : {
                        type : 'hbox',
                        //align : 'stretch'

                    },

                    //takes all possible space
                    flex : 1
                }]}


    ]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eternasparta/yxeSG/

thank you all!

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what you are trying to achieve or better explain it? I don't really understand what you are trying to make.

Comment: was the below answer helpful?

Comment: it's not exactly what was expected, sorry; or i have to minify better my example (cause i've already a viewport).

Answer (score 0):

View port is the key element that monitors browser size.
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/6r7Dd/

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 200,
    title: 'Panel 1',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Panel 2',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Right P',
            padding: '5'
        }]
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [myPanel]
});
```

Comment: Using a box layout with a single item doesn't make sense, should be a fit layout.

Comment: He wants to control width, fit will take full width. I am not quite sure what the end result is supposed to be. I am just guessing here.